# Using Google Earth Pro style templates

Tags: kml, google-earth

When importing a CSV file into Google Earth Pro, I am asked if I want to apply a style template. I do. I'd like to be able to load a previously defined template rather than have to set the style options manually each time I load a file. After setting all of the options in the "Style Template Options" dialog, it appears to save two styling-related files: template_name.kdx and template_name.kst.

My template is fairly involved with a lot of subfolders, so manually setting it up in the dialog box every time is tedious. It looks like the basic settings are recorded in the .kst file. How do I apply a saved template to my imported records?

I would also like to set icon size (or is it scale) in the template. Currently, I can only control the icon image/href used. I would also like to set the label in the template. I have been unable to find docs/specs for the .kst format. Are there additional configuration options that can be manually edited in the .kst file that are not configurable from the dialog box?

Comment: Don't have an answer either, it seems very inconvenient that you have to manipulate those extra files. Hopefully someone sees this!

Answer (score 0):

The .KST style template HAS to be saved to your

```
%AppData\LocalLow\Google\GoogleEarth\My Style Templates
```

Folder in order to be able to use it. Otherwise google earth pro just assumes that you don't have any style templates and tries to force you to set one up. (which was not very intuitive) Hopefully that helps.